# Ajaxify PushState pushing CSS files?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I'm creating a simple website and now I'm using the Ajaxify library to make page transitions look great. 
The problem is: my pages have both a global CSS file (used in the whole site) and specific CSS files (one file for each page, with specific content).
When I change page with Ajaxify, it pushes the content, however doesn't push the specific CSS links in the *head*, so the site gets buggy. Any ideas on how to modify Ajaxify to also look for *link* tags and push them?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [jQuery](http://jquery.com) (which I think is a requirement for Ajaxify), then you can easily manually append new style sheets to the head after the page transition has completed:

```
$('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="page-specific-style.css" type="text/css" />');
```